# MySQL trigger to delete rows that is 1 day old not working

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have tried to create a trigger that will delete from a table (user_data) the rows that are 1 day old after insertion of a new row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_user_data
AFTER INSERT ON user_data
FOR EACH ROW
DELETE FROM user_data
WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

But, it's not working. nothing is deleted after insertion. here date is a datetime field. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure you actually have items that should be deleted? The syntax looks correct to me

Comment: i have items in the table @Kay Nelson

Comment: And if you execute `DELETE FROM user_data WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` outside of the trigger it removes the items?

Comment: yes it removes @Kay Nelson

Comment: Ok can you run `SHOW TRIGGERS FROM database` to make sure it exists?

Comment: yes it exists. I have checked @Kay Nelson

Comment: Ok im out of ideas :-)

Comment: You cannot action a table in a trigger which was fired by an action on a table.